# How can permissions be retained when a schema is overwritten in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a schema that is deleted by an automatic process and then recreated, but since it is a new schema, it loses the permissions each time.

Is there any automatic way to ensure that the permissions are not lost?

I have tried giving access to all the database (this will be a solution for my use case, even it is not the desired one) modifying the default privileges of the tables creatd by the user, but it is not possible to grant the access.